# σ-finite space iff $f$ finite almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

I haven't found any other question that answered my problem so...

If $μ,ν $ are  two measures in measure space $(X, \mathcal{A})$, $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ measurable function such that $ν(A)=\int_{A}fdμ$  $\forall A\in\mathcal{A} $  prove that $ν$ is σ-finite iff $f<\infty$ $μ$- almost everywhere.

I have proved$(\Rightarrow) $. For $ (\Leftarrow)$ I only thought this:

for $Z=[f=\infty]$(elements in $X$ for which $f(x)=\infty$), $μ(Ζ)=0<\infty$ so $ν(Ζ)<\infty$. Let $B=X\backslash Z$ and $A_n=\{x \in B: n\leq f<n+1\}\in \mathcal{A}$ because $ f$ is measurable.

I tried to prove that $ν(A_n)<\infty$ but I don't think it's true. Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't think the equivalence is true because if $f$ is the constant function with value $1$ then $\nu = \mu$. However, we did not impose any assumption on $\mu$ - so effectively it would follow that every mesure is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @bs_math Well that's what the exercise was asking for.  I see your point. Though there is no other assumption. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly false without some extra assumption on $\mu$. If $f \equiv 1$ then $\nu =\mu$ so $\nu$ cannot be $\sigma$-finite unless $\mu$ is.

However, if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite then the assertion is true. Suppose $B_n$'s are disjoint sets of finite $\mu$-measure whose union is $X$. Let $A_n$'s and $Z$ be as in your attempt. Then $\nu (A_n \cap B_m) \leq (n+1) \mu (B_n) <\infty$ for all $n,m$ and $X$ is covered by the countable collection of sets $\{Z, A_n \cap B_m : n,m \geq 1\}$.

Comment: Thanks! I will solve it with the extra assumption and tell my teacher.